# How to make this page transaction effect on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How to make this page transaction effect on flutter

Example:

[instagram stories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efPfR.gif)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** 
With package https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector, you can detect SwipeDown 
and In OnSwipeDown() execute your route change logical with PageRouteBuilder

```
SwipeDetector(
    child: ... //You Widget Tree here
    ),
    onSwipeUp: () {
        setState(() {
            _swipeDirection = "Swipe Up";
        });
    },
    onSwipeDown: () {
        setState(() {
            _swipeDirection = "Swipe Down";
        });
    },
    onSwipeLeft: () {
      setState(() {
        _swipeDirection = "Swipe Left";
      });
    },
    onSwipeRight: () {
      setState(() {
        _swipeDirection = "Swipe Right";
      });
    },
)
```

please use PageRouteBuilder to build animation
full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              return SlideRightRoute(widget:HomePage());
              break;
            case '/second':
              return SlideRightRoute(widget:SecondHome());
              break;
          }
        }
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
          },
          child: Text('Second Home'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class SecondHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Home'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SlideRightRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget widget;
  SlideRightRoute({this.widget})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      return widget;
    },
    transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        Widget child) {
      return new SlideTransition(
        position: new Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
          end: Offset.zero,
        ).animate(animation),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for, if you look at the page it closes by sliding down and at the same time it has that animation, what I'm looking for is a way to close the page by sliding down and at the same time with an animation.

Comment: I have edit answer. you can do this with package swipedetector

Comment: tanks, I'll take a look